# Wix CopyFile only on target machine

Tags: wix, wix3

I need to be able to copy a file that exists on the target machines hard-drive based on a registry setting that holds the folder path.

I have been trying to get this going for a day or two and am having difficulty, can anyone help?

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
<Component Id="MyComponent" Guid="E5FF53DE-1739-42c4-BE37-60F810C9CD69">  
 <Condition>MYTESTDIR</Condition>
 <CopyFile Id="fileToCopy.datCopy" SourceName="[MYTESTDIR]fileToCopy.dat" DestinationProperty="WEBSERVICEBINFOLDER" /> 
</Component>
```

You can populate MYTESTDIR with a value from the registry using a RegistrySearch.

Answer (score 1):

You can first search your registry for the file as follows:

```
<Property Id="PROPERTYNAME" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SomeID"
          Root="HKLM"
          Type="raw"
          Key="SOFTWARE\SomeFolder\SomeSubFolder"
          Win64="yes"
          Name="InstallPath">
    <DirectorySearch Id="REQUIREDDIRECTORY" AssignToProperty="yes" Depth="1" Path="THEEXPECTEDPATH">
    </DirectorySearch>
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
```

Then use a Custom Action to set the file name

```
      <CustomAction Id="SETFILE"
      Property="FILE"
      Value="[PROPERTYNAME]file.extension" />
```

and then copy file as described by the previous answer...

```
      <CopyFile Id="fileToCopy.datCopy" SourceName="[FILE]" DestinationProperty="[YOURDESTINATION]" />
```